# overflowing div static width

Tags: html, width

I have a div which is filled with dynamic content. The div width is set to 680px, however if the content exceeds this width, rather than wrapping, it just keep going on a single line creating a very wide div.

What should I do to enforce the 680px of the div and force the dynamic content to wrap within those restraints?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following in your *div's* css class:

```
.someClass {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 680px;
 }
```

Hope it helps!